# Elastic Search update stats per day

Tags: elasticsearch

Would like to check how many document update request my index actually received per day in elastic search.
I was assuming that this could be done using [_stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-stats.html) API, however upon examining the results it is not clear where I can find the update stats.

API used : https://{ip}:{port}/uat-esobject/_stats

```js
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 345347,
                "deleted": 25661
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 101712783
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 11920279,
                "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                "index_current": 0,
                "index_failed": 2,
                "delete_total": 5484650,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                "delete_current": 0,
                "noop_update_total": 0,
                "is_throttled": false,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 27243917,
                "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                "exists_total": 27182299,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                "missing_total": 61618,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 64625,
                "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 32275,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "scroll_total": 480,
                "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                "scroll_current": 0,
                "suggest_total": 0,
                "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                "suggest_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 165195,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                "total_docs": 2226667303,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 1752437,
                "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                "listeners": 0
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 4669,
                "periodic": 0,
                "total_time_in_millis": 92817
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 1670809,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52566
            },
            "query_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total_count": 315448,
                "hit_count": 75641,
                "miss_count": 239807,
                "cache_size": 0,
                "cache_count": 13883,
                "evictions": 13883
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 39,
                "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 146754,
                "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
            },
            "request_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0,
                "hit_count": 0,
                "miss_count": 545
            },
            "recovery": {
                "current_as_source": 0,
                "current_as_target": 0,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 345347,
                "deleted": 25661
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 101712783
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 11920279,
                "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                "index_current": 0,
                "index_failed": 2,
                "delete_total": 5484650,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                "delete_current": 0,
                "noop_update_total": 0,
                "is_throttled": false,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 27243917,
                "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                "exists_total": 27182299,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                "missing_total": 61618,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 64625,
                "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 32275,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "scroll_total": 480,
                "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                "scroll_current": 0,
                "suggest_total": 0,
                "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                "suggest_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 165195,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                "total_docs": 2226667303,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 1752437,
                "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                "listeners": 0
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 4669,
                "periodic": 0,
                "total_time_in_millis": 92817
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 1670809,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52566
            },
            "query_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total_count": 315448,
                "hit_count": 75641,
                "miss_count": 239807,
                "cache_size": 0,
                "cache_count": 13883,
                "evictions": 13883
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 39,
                "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 146754,
                "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
            },
            "request_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0,
                "hit_count": 0,
                "miss_count": 545
            },
            "recovery": {
                "current_as_source": 0,
                "current_as_target": 0,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "indices": {
        "uat-esobject": {
            "uuid": "geINqqarQLWbf-bzkdJIhA",
            "primaries": {
                "docs": {
                    "count": 345347,
                    "deleted": 25661
                },
                "store": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 101712783
                },
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 11920279,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "index_failed": 2,
                    "delete_total": 5484650,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                    "delete_current": 0,
                    "noop_update_total": 0,
                    "is_throttled": false,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "get": {
                    "total": 27243917,
                    "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                    "exists_total": 27182299,
                    "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                    "missing_total": 61618,
                    "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                    "current": 0
                },
                "search": {
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_total": 64625,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "fetch_total": 32275,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                    "fetch_current": 0,
                    "scroll_total": 480,
                    "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                    "scroll_current": 0,
                    "suggest_total": 0,
                    "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "suggest_current": 0
                },
                "merges": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "current_docs": 0,
                    "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total": 165195,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                    "total_docs": 2226667303,
                    "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                    "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
                },
                "refresh": {
                    "total": 1752437,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                    "listeners": 0
                },
                "flush": {
                    "total": 4669,
                    "periodic": 0,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 92817
                },
                "warmer": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "total": 1670809,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52566
                },
                "query_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total_count": 315448,
                    "hit_count": 75641,
                    "miss_count": 239807,
                    "cache_size": 0,
                    "cache_count": 13883,
                    "evictions": 13883
                },
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0
                },
                "completion": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "segments": {
                    "count": 39,
                    "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                    "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                    "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                    "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                    "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                    "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                    "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                    "file_sizes": {}
                },
                "translog": {
                    "operations": 146754,
                    "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                    "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                    "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                    "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
                },
                "request_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0,
                    "hit_count": 0,
                    "miss_count": 545
                },
                "recovery": {
                    "current_as_source": 0,
                    "current_as_target": 0,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            },
            "total": {
                "docs": {
                    "count": 345347,
                    "deleted": 25661
                },
                "store": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 101712783
                },
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 11920279,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "index_failed": 2,
                    "delete_total": 5484650,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                    "delete_current": 0,
                    "noop_update_total": 0,
                    "is_throttled": false,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "get": {
                    "total": 27243917,
                    "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                    "exists_total": 27182299,
                    "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                    "missing_total": 61618,
                    "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                    "current": 0
                },
                "search": {
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_total": 64625,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "fetch_total": 32275,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                    "fetch_current": 0,
                    "scroll_total": 480,
                    "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                    "scroll_current": 0,
                    "suggest_total": 0,
                    "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "suggest_current": 0
                },
                "merges": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "current_docs": 0,
                    "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total": 165195,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                    "total_docs": 2226667303,
                    "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                    "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
                },
                "refresh": {
                    "total": 1752437,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                    "listeners": 0
                },
                "flush": {
                    "total": 4669,
                    "periodic": 0,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 92817
                },
                "warmer": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "total": 1670809,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52566
                },
                "query_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total_count": 315448,
                    "hit_count": 75641,
                    "miss_count": 239807,
                    "cache_size": 0,
                    "cache_count": 13883,
                    "evictions": 13883
                },
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0
                },
                "completion": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "segments": {
                    "count": 39,
                    "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                    "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                    "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                    "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                    "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                    "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                    "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                    "file_sizes": {}
                },
                "translog": {
                    "operations": 146754,
                    "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                    "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                    "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                    "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
                },
                "request_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0,
                    "hit_count": 0,
                    "miss_count": 545
                },
                "recovery": {
                    "current_as_source": 0,
                    "current_as_target": 0,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 345347,
                "deleted": 25661
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 101712783
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 11920279,
                "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                "index_current": 0,
                "index_failed": 2,
                "delete_total": 5484650,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                "delete_current": 0,
                "noop_update_total": 0,
                "is_throttled": false,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 27243917,
                "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                "exists_total": 27182299,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                "missing_total": 61618,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 64625,
                "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 32275,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "scroll_total": 480,
                "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                "scroll_current": 0,
                "suggest_total": 0,
                "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                "suggest_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 165195,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                "total_docs": 2226667303,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 1752437,
                "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                "listeners": 0
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 4669,
                "periodic": 0,
                "total_time_in_millis": 92817
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 1670809,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52566
            },
            "query_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total_count": 315448,
                "hit_count": 75641,
                "miss_count": 239807,
                "cache_size": 0,
                "cache_count": 13883,
                "evictions": 13883
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 39,
                "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 146754,
                "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
            },
            "request_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0,
                "hit_count": 0,
                "miss_count": 545
            },
            "recovery": {
                "current_as_source": 0,
                "current_as_target": 0,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 345347,
                "deleted": 25661
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 101712783
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 11920279,
                "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                "index_current": 0,
                "index_failed": 2,
                "delete_total": 5484650,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                "delete_current": 0,
                "noop_update_total": 0,
                "is_throttled": false,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 27243917,
                "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                "exists_total": 27182299,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                "missing_total": 61618,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 64625,
                "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 32275,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "scroll_total": 480,
                "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                "scroll_current": 0,
                "suggest_total": 0,
                "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                "suggest_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 165195,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                "total_docs": 2226667303,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 1752437,
                "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                "listeners": 0
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 4669,
                "periodic": 0,
                "total_time_in_millis": 92817
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 1670809,
                "total_time_in_millis": 52566
            },
            "query_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total_count": 315448,
                "hit_count": 75641,
                "miss_count": 239807,
                "cache_size": 0,
                "cache_count": 13883,
                "evictions": 13883
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 39,
                "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 146754,
                "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
            },
            "request_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0,
                "hit_count": 0,
                "miss_count": 545
            },
            "recovery": {
                "current_as_source": 0,
                "current_as_target": 0,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "indices": {
        "uat-esobject": {
            "uuid": "geINqqarQLWbf-bzkdJIhA",
            "primaries": {
                "docs": {
                    "count": 345347,
                    "deleted": 25661
                },
                "store": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 101712783
                },
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 11920279,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "index_failed": 2,
                    "delete_total": 5484650,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                    "delete_current": 0,
                    "noop_update_total": 0,
                    "is_throttled": false,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "get": {
                    "total": 27243917,
                    "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                    "exists_total": 27182299,
                    "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                    "missing_total": 61618,
                    "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                    "current": 0
                },
                "search": {
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_total": 64625,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "fetch_total": 32275,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                    "fetch_current": 0,
                    "scroll_total": 480,
                    "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                    "scroll_current": 0,
                    "suggest_total": 0,
                    "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "suggest_current": 0
                },
                "merges": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "current_docs": 0,
                    "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total": 165195,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                    "total_docs": 2226667303,
                    "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                    "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
                },
                "refresh": {
                    "total": 1752437,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                    "listeners": 0
                },
                "flush": {
                    "total": 4669,
                    "periodic": 0,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 92817
                },
                "warmer": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "total": 1670809,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52566
                },
                "query_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total_count": 315448,
                    "hit_count": 75641,
                    "miss_count": 239807,
                    "cache_size": 0,
                    "cache_count": 13883,
                    "evictions": 13883
                },
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0
                },
                "completion": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "segments": {
                    "count": 39,
                    "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                    "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                    "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                    "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                    "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                    "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                    "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                    "file_sizes": {}
                },
                "translog": {
                    "operations": 146754,
                    "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                    "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                    "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                    "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
                },
                "request_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0,
                    "hit_count": 0,
                    "miss_count": 545
                },
                "recovery": {
                    "current_as_source": 0,
                    "current_as_target": 0,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            },
            "total": {
                "docs": {
                    "count": 345347,
                    "deleted": 25661
                },
                "store": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 101712783
                },
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 11920279,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 3122742,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "index_failed": 2,
                    "delete_total": 5484650,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 62083,
                    "delete_current": 0,
                    "noop_update_total": 0,
                    "is_throttled": false,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "get": {
                    "total": 27243917,
                    "time_in_millis": 2149493,
                    "exists_total": 27182299,
                    "exists_time_in_millis": 2149177,
                    "missing_total": 61618,
                    "missing_time_in_millis": 316,
                    "current": 0
                },
                "search": {
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_total": 64625,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 47774,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "fetch_total": 32275,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 72630,
                    "fetch_current": 0,
                    "scroll_total": 480,
                    "scroll_time_in_millis": 515310,
                    "scroll_current": 0,
                    "suggest_total": 0,
                    "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "suggest_current": 0
                },
                "merges": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "current_docs": 0,
                    "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total": 165195,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52423254,
                    "total_docs": 2226667303,
                    "total_size_in_bytes": 597658087755,
                    "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
                },
                "refresh": {
                    "total": 1752437,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 27481459,
                    "listeners": 0
                },
                "flush": {
                    "total": 4669,
                    "periodic": 0,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 92817
                },
                "warmer": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "total": 1670809,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 52566
                },
                "query_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total_count": 315448,
                    "hit_count": 75641,
                    "miss_count": 239807,
                    "cache_size": 0,
                    "cache_count": 13883,
                    "evictions": 13883
                },
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0
                },
                "completion": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "segments": {
                    "count": 39,
                    "memory_in_bytes": 971368,
                    "terms_memory_in_bytes": 886569,
                    "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 38544,
                    "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "norms_memory_in_bytes": 29952,
                    "points_memory_in_bytes": 12539,
                    "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3764,
                    "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                    "file_sizes": {}
                },
                "translog": {
                    "operations": 146754,
                    "size_in_bytes": 71681210,
                    "uncommitted_operations": 176,
                    "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 87471,
                    "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
                },
                "request_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "evictions": 0,
                    "hit_count": 0,
                    "miss_count": 545
                },
                "recovery": {
                    "current_as_source": 0,
                    "current_as_target": 0,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These stats shows the value from the last restart of ES node, what you can do is write a cron job which check the value of these stats same time everyday, that way you can subtract the today count from yesterday's count and get the stats you are looking for.

And under indexing section `index_total` is the total index operation at the index since last node restart which you should use for your use-case.